# How can I find a file's path in the text encoding used by PosteRazor?

Tags: nautilus, encoding, workflow, poster

[PosteRazor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18698/printing-a-poster-over-several-sheets-of-paper/18701#18701) uses an apparently outdated GUI that is incapable of properly displaying my filenames:

[image: PosteRazor - Load an input image]

For the sake of convenience, I want to be able to open any file in PosteRazor by copying and pasting its path from Nautilus. This works in other applications, but sadly, PosteRazor is unable to understand the path:

[image: PosteRazor - Load an input image]

How can I convert the path that Nautilus generates into a text encoding that is compatible with PosteRazor?

The Ubuntu package for PosteRazor lists a dependency on the Fast Light Toolkit (FLTK). Its [programmer's documentation on Unicode](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/unicode.html) looks like it might contain the necessary information to answer my question, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

### Details

- Some sample content:

  - A path as it natively appears in Nautilus:

    ```
    /home/ak/café/north-america.jpg
    ```
  - The same path as it natively appears in PosteRazor:

    [image: The path <code>/home/ak/café/north-america.jpg</code> displayed in PosteRazor]
  - The clipboard contents after copying the path from Nautilus:

    ```
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target TARGETS
    TIMESTAMP
    TARGETS
    MULTIPLE
    x-special/gnome-copied-files
    text/uri-list
    UTF8_STRING
    COMPOUND_TEXT
    TEXT
    STRING
    text/plain;charset=utf-8
    text/plain
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 e9 2f 6e 6f  |/home/ak/caf./no|
    00000010  72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65 72  69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67     |rth-america.jpg|
    0000001f
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target UTF8_STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65  72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67  |orth-america.jpg|
    00000020
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target text/plain | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 5c 75 30 30  |/home/ak/caf\u00|
    00000010  65 39 2f 6e 6f 72 74 68  2d 61 6d 65 72 69 63 61  |e9/north-america|
    00000020  2e 6a 70 67                                       |.jpg|
    00000024
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65  72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67  |orth-america.jpg|
    00000020
    ```
  - The clipboard contents after copying the path from PosteRazor:

    ```
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target TARGETS
    STRING
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65  72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67  |orth-america.jpg|
    00000020
    ```
  - PosteRazor after copying the path from Nautilus and pasting it into PosteRazor:

    [image: PosteRazor with OK button grayed out]
  - PosteRazor after copying the path from PosteRazor and pasting it into PosteRazor:

    [image: PosteRazor with OK button active]
  - The path copied from PosteRazor and pasted into Chromium:

    ```
    /home/ak/café/norrth-america.jpg
    ```
  - The path copied from PosteRazor and pasted into Chromium and then copied from Chromium and pasted back into PosteRazor:

    [image: PosteRazor with OK button active]
  - The clipboard contents after copying that from Chromium:

    ```
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target TARGETS
    TIMESTAMP
    TARGETS
    MULTIPLE
    SAVE_TARGETS
    COMPOUND_TEXT
    STRING
    TEXT
    UTF8_STRING
    text/plain
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 72 74 68 2d 61 6d  65 72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70  |orrth-america.jp|
    00000020  67                                                |g|
    00000021
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target UTF8_STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 72 74 68 2d 61 6d  65 72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70  |orrth-america.jp|
    00000020  67                                                |g|
    00000021
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target text/plain | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 72 74 68 2d 61 6d  65 72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70  |orrth-america.jp|
    00000020  67                                                |g|
    00000021
    ```
  - The path copied from PosteRazor and pasted into GNOME Terminal:

    [image: Path appears correctly in GNOME Terminal]
  - The path copied from PosteRazor and pasted into GNOME Terminal and then copied from GNOME Terminal and pasted back into PosteRazor:

    [image: PosteRazor with OK button grayed out]
  - The clipboard contents after copying that from GNOME Terminal:

    ```
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target TARGETS
    TIMESTAMP
    TARGETS
    MULTIPLE
    SAVE_TARGETS
    UTF8_STRING
    COMPOUND_TEXT
    TEXT
    STRING
    text/plain;charset=utf-8
    text/plain
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 e9 2f 6e 6f  |/home/ak/caf./no|
    00000010  72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65 72  69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67     |rth-america.jpg|
    0000001f
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target UTF8_STRING | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65  72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67  |orth-america.jpg|
    00000020
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target 'text/plain' | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 5c 75 30 30  |/home/ak/caf\u00|
    00000010  65 39 2f 6e 6f 72 74 68  2d 61 6d 65 72 69 63 61  |e9/north-america|
    00000020  2e 6a 70 67                                       |.jpg|
    00000024
    $ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' | hexdump -C
    00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 61 6b  2f 63 61 66 c3 a9 2f 6e  |/home/ak/caf../n|
    00000010  6f 72 74 68 2d 61 6d 65  72 69 63 61 2e 6a 70 67  |orth-america.jpg|
    00000020
    ```

Comment: Possibly related: http://sourceforge.net/projects/posterazor/forums/forum/475342/topic/3655054

Comment: Yes, thank you. Why is it marked for closure, where, and by whom?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up - this is what is going on. If you need more time then I will remove my flag and let it sit other wise this should be removed, Regards

Comment: I still want to know the answer to this question. Why do you think this post should be removed, and what would be the benefit of my re-posting it?

Comment: Started a bounty because this question is 9 months old. Lets see if we can get an answer.

Comment: Can you post a sample path here which PosteRazor cannot interpret?

Comment: @green7 I've added some sample content to study.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update:*** Following command can be used:

```
xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | iconv --from-code ISO-8859-15 --to-code UTF-8 | xclip -in -selection clipboard
```

For explanation read the full answer.

---

To completely understand the answer, you need to have an understanding of Unicode code points and unicode encoding.

Below are short definitions and explanations of the required terms, but I recommend you read about them from the sources mentioned at the end of the answer.

- **Unicode Code Space:** A range of integers from 0 to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub>.
- **Unicode Code Points:** Any value in the Unicode codespace. A code point corresponds to a character, though not all code points are assigned to encoded characters.
- **UTF-8:** UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format - 8-bit) is a *variable-width encoding* that can represent every character in the Unicode character set. UCS stands for Universal Character Set.

  The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920 characters need two bytes to encode. This covers the remainder of almost all Latin-derived alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic, Coptic, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac and Tāna alphabets, as well as Combining Diacritical Marks.

  This indicates that the character `é` which is causing problems takes two bytes to encode in UTF-8. We will verify it using some commands.
- **ISO/IEC 8859-15:** 8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets.

---

To test, I made a directory `/home/green/Pictures/café/`.

**After copying the location from `nautilus`, the outputs of the commands were as follows:**

***Command #1:***

```
$ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 67 72  65 65 6e 2f 50 69 63 74  |/home/green/Pict|
00000010  75 72 65 73 2f 63 61 66  e9 2f                    |ures/caf./|
0000001a
```

Note that the encoding of `café` is `63 61 66 e9`, which is all right as the Unicode Code Point U+00E9 represents `{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}` or `é`.

***Command #2:***

```
$ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target UTF8_STRING | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 67 72  65 65 6e 2f 50 69 63 74  |/home/green/Pict|
00000010  75 72 65 73 2f 63 61 66  c3 a9 2f                 |ures/caf../|
0000001b
```

In the above output, `café` is encoded as `63 61 66 c3 a9`. It is all right too because the UTF-8 encoding of code point U+00E9 (corresponding to `é`) is `\xC3\xA9` (`\x` is used to represent that the following characters are hexadecimal numbers).

`\xC3` represents 1 byte and so does `\xA9`. Thus, UTF-8 needs 2 bytes to represent `é`.

**After copying the same text from `PosteRazor` the outputs of the commands were:**

***Command #1:***

```
$ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 67 72  65 65 6e 2f 50 69 63 74  |/home/green/Pict|
00000010  75 72 65 73 2f 63 61 66  c3 a9 2f                 |ures/caf../|
0000001b
```

Clearly, the Unicode Code Points are messed up. Now, we have two code points (`c3` and `a9`) where there should be only one (`e9`).

Unsurprisingly, the two code points i.e. `U+00C3` and `U+00A9` stand for `{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE}` AND `{COPYRIGHT SIGN}`, which is what we saw in `PosteRazor`.

***Command #2:***

```
$ xclip -out -selection clipboard -target UTF8_STRING | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 67 72  65 65 6e 2f 50 69 63 74  |/home/green/Pict|
00000010  75 72 65 73 2f 63 61 66  c3 a9 2f                 |ures/caf../|
0000001b
```

The output for this command seems to have remained unchanged, but there is a subtle difference.

In the previous output `\xc3\xa9` formed a single character whereas now `\xc3` forms one character on its own and `\xa9` forms another character (which are  `Ã` and `©`, respectively).

---

Now we know *what* is happening, but *how* is it happening?
To simulate the same thing, we will use Python. I'm using Python 3.3.0 here.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> a = u'/home/green/Pictures/café'
>>> a
'/home/green/Pictures/café'
>>> a = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
b'/home/green/Pictures/caf\xc3\xa9'
>>> a = a.decode('iso-8859-15')
>>> a
'/home/green/Pictures/cafÃ©'
>>> a = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
b'/home/green/Pictures/caf\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9'
```

You can see that if we first encode the string using UTF-8 and then decode using ISO-8859-15, then we get the same string which we get while using `PosteRazor`.

Now, notice the following code. Here too, we have copied and pasted the location from nautilus:

```
>>> z = u'/home/green/Pictures/café'
>>> z
'/home/green/Pictures/café'
>>> z = z.encode('iso-8859-15')
>>> z
b'/home/green/Pictures/caf\xe9'
>>> z = z.decode('iso-8859-15')
>>> z
'/home/green/Pictures/café'
```

Had we encoded the string using ISO-8859-15 initially, we'd have gotten the perfect result.

Note that `\xe9` is the encoding for `é` in ISO-8859-15, which apparently needs one byte. This is the same as the Unicode code point U+00E9 which, when encoded in UTF-8, needs 2 bytes and is represented by `\xc3\xa9`.

Now that we know what and how everything is going on, how do we correct it? Well, you can either convert the paths to the ISO-8859-15 character set or you can just use the GUI for selecting files.

---

***Sources and further information:***

- [*Unicode 6.2.0 PDF - Part 3.4: Character and encoding*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G2212)
- [*Unicode Glossary*](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/)
- [*Wikipedia - UTF-8*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
- [*Wikipedia - List of Unicode Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_Extended-A)
- [*UTF-8 Complete Character List*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)
- [*Wikipedia - ISO/IEC 8859-15*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)
- [*ISO 8859-15 Complete Character List*](http://man.he.net/man7/iso-8859-15)
- [*StackOverflow - Answer to "php to rtf, é becomes Ã©"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690502/1626345)
- [*StackOverflow - Decoding double encoded utf8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1177316/1626345)

Comment: Awesome detective work! I've assigned a keyboard shortcut to transcode the clipboard contents using [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/): `xclip -out -selection clipboard -target STRING | iconv --from-code ISO-8859-15 --to-code UTF-8 | xclip -in -selection clipboard`

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll edit the answer to include the command. :)